Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
I found a problem with gradle
When I try to run a test, I meet an arror like
Execution failed for task ':io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main()'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

I checked all decisions from google but nothing works for me
JAVA_HOME - correct
Java version - correct
When I specify in IDEA - settings - Build - Gradle - Build and run using =  Intellij IDEA - there is no error, but when GRADLE is specified - I match it
cucumber main class - correct
Info
alexander@MacBook-Pro-admin ~ % echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
alexander@MacBook-Pro-admin ~ % java -version
java version "17.0.12" 2024-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286, mixed mode, sharing)

Nothing from this topic helped(

Try to do what the error message says. And please read the "Help others reproduce the problem" of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

@M.P.Korstanje I tried what the system says but can't solve the problem
